# How to disable Chrome kiosk mode?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, kiosk

I started Chrome in kiosk mode, like this:

```
start chrome --kiosk "http://google.com"
```

Now everytime I open Chrome it opens in kiosk mode and I can't find how to turn this off.

I tried some commands at http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ but no luck sofar. Looking for a solution that doesn't require reinstalling.

Comment: Ah, I needed to close Google background apps...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome doesn't exit kiosk mode until the application is shutdown. Close all background processes from Google in your Operating System's task manager or go to Windows' Task Bar in the lower right hand corner and right click on 'Google Chrome' or it's icon and click 'Exit'.

Comment: "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."